# PowerShell 7 - how to run a command on windows?

Tags: powershell

I just want to run a `docker` command with parameters from PowerShell 7 script. When I just use the command:

```
if ($isRunning -eq $false) {
   docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 -v <some_path> <image_name>
}
```

it works. But I need to use a variable in this command, so I changed it to:

```
& "docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 -v $script:myPath\:/usr/local/whatever"
```

And it runs but then it tells me *The term 'docker run -it ...' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet...*. It seems like PowerShell script does not have the same $PATH environment variable value as cmd.

What's wrong here?

Comment: try using an array instead of embedding the expression in a string

Comment: what do you mean? it seems the problem is with $PATH somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might work, passing the arguments to your `docker` command as an array of arguments instead of embedding all the expression in a string which is currently failing because PowerShell is trying to find a command with the name of the entire expression (`docker run -it ...`).

```
if (-not $isRunning) {
    docker @(
        'run'
        '-it'
        '--rm'
        '-p'
        '8080:8080'
        '-v'
        "$script:myPath\:/usr/local/whatever"
    )
}
```